# How to interpret QSphere visualisation

Tags: qiskit, bloch-sphere

AFAIK, $n$ qubits together can be described by using a column vector (also called State vector) of $2^n$ complex amplitudes such that sum of the squares of mod of all these complex amplitudes will be $1$.

However, as per below snippet for qsphere visualisation, what does the *spikes* of different colours denote?

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_qsphere
num_qb = 3
my_sv = random_statevector(2**num_qb)  
plot_state_qsphere(my_sv)
```

[image: qsphere of 3 qubit]

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDudoiJ_lh8) nicely explains it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the points on the spike shows the probability of the state and the color represents the phase  of the state , for example state $|000\rangle$ is blue so it has a phase of 0 and the point is larger that the rest of them so it has the highest probability. state $|110\rangle$ is the second largest to it, so it has the second largest probability, and it is green so its phase is in pi to 3*pi/2 range. you can check [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/docs/iqx/visualizations#q-sphere-view) and [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.plot_state_qsphere.html) for more information about qsphere

Comment: One correction - the size of the points implies upon the **probability amplitudes** of each computational basis states. The color implies upon the phase of each amplitude. The term “probability” refers to the magnitude squared of the probability amplitude.